# How to retrieve the item (of a p:selectOneListbox) firing a p:contextMenu

Tags: ajax, primefaces

My env. is : Primefaces 5.1; jdk 7.0.40;JSF 2.0 (Mojarra 2.03-FCS); Tomcat 7.0.
I build a p:selectOneListbox and the p:contextMenu : all works fine. The problem is : how to retrieve which item in the list fired the contextMenu  (that correctly appears on right click)  when no selection was yet performed ?

```
    <h:form id="recipeFilesForm">
    <h:outputText value="Recipe files" style="position:relative;left:40px;font-size:0.9em;" />
    <p:selectOneListbox id="recipeFileList"   value="#{RecipeFormMngr0.selecteduserFileIndex}" 
        style="width:190px;font-size:0.7em;text-align:left;position:relative;left:-24px">
        <f:selectItems value="#{RecipeFormMngr0.recipeFileNamesItems}" var="u" itemLabel="#{u.label}" itemValue="#{u.value}">
        </f:selectItems>
        <p:ajax event="click"  listener="#{RecipeFormMngr0.selecteduserFileIndexSelected}"  />
    </p:selectOneListbox>
    <p:contextMenu for="recipeFileList" style="font-size:0.7em;">
        <p:menuitem value="Show"   actionListener="#{RecipeFormMngr0.showRecipeContent}" ajax="true" process=":loginForm0_1:userSettingTab:recipeFilesForm" />
        <p:menuitem value="Delete" actionListener="#{RecipeFormMngr0.deleteRecipeFile}" ajax="true" process=":loginForm0_1:userSettingTab:recipeFilesForm" />
        <p:menuitem value="Edit"   actionListener="#{RecipeFormMngr0.editRecipeContent}" ajax="true" process=":loginForm0_1:userSettingTab:recipeFilesForm" />
    </p:contextMenu>
</h:form>
```